# all images are shown in Slider of wordpress till page is not fully loaded

Tags: wordpress

i am using a slider js named as `easySlider1.js` for worspress. its working fine but till the time whole page is not fully loaded it show all the images of slider for a moment till the page is not loaded. as soon as page is fully loaded then it working fine.but it seems odd that it show all the images while page is in loading process. so please tell me how can i solve the problem. i want that all the images of slider should not show while page load. i try for it but cannot get the solution.so please tell me how can i solve the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the page looks like, but with the information you gave I came up with the following:

If the images are surrounded with a html-tag like div or p, then you can add css to hide the images while loading and show the images when the page is fully loaded.

If you have this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="image_gallery">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
...
</body>
```

Then change it to this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="image_gallery" style="display:none;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
...
<!-- insert script just above the body endtag -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('div#image_gallery').show();
</script>
</body>
```

jQuery must be loaded for this to work.